preventDefault() not preventing page redirect on form submission
I have a simple form being submitted into a third-party form/db location (Acoustic) and I'm trying to prevent the page from being redirected after submission.
    <form method="post" action="my-form-url-goes-in-here">
      // form labels and fields
    </form>
    <button type="submit" id="mybtn">Submit</button>

I've tried using preventDefault() and return false as options to override that behavior but for some reason they don't work.
    document.querySelector("#mybtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
      document.querySelector("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        return false;
      });
    });

What are some options for achieving this behavior.

You are calling the form's submit method with this: document.querySelector("form").submit(.... I think you can remove this line altogether. `document.querySelector("#mybtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});`


In general form submit event handlers should be attached directly to the form's submit event, not the submit buttons

Also note that you can't submit the form and not redirect to the form action URL at the same time. Directing the browser to the form's URL is what the submit action is. You'll have to submit the form programmatically with Ajax if you don't want the browser to navigate to the new page.

@mykaf thanks for that suggestion, it didn't seem to prevent the page from redirecting after submission.

guyincognito is correct. You cannot use the form action attribute in this way.

Generally, a form submission is similar to following a link: Both are HTTP requests with navigation. This means we cannot naively prevent navigation without affecting the request.
You want to perform a request without navigation, when a form submission would happen. This is Ajax, the concept of asynchronous requests.
To do this, we can prevent the form submission and perform an Ajax request instead. Example with the Fetch API:


const form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  // Prevent form submission
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // Populate options with form values
  const options = {
    method: form.method,
    body: new FormData(form)
  };
  
  // Perform request
  const promiseResponse = fetch(form.action, options);
  
  // (Optional) Use response
  // Note: Will throw error because SO snippets are sandboxed
  promiseResponse
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Response code:", response.status, response.statusText);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("Error:", error);
    });
});
<form method="post" action="https://stackoverflow.com/">
  <label>Text: <input name="text"></label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>



Note:

We need to manually populate the request because fetch() is unaware that it is replacing the form submission.
Buttons submit their form by default; no form.submit() via a click handler needed.


Preventing the submit event directly (instead of e.g. a precursory click event) has several benefits:

A form submission is always the direct result of a non-cancelled submit event.
A submit event may be the result of a click event, among others.
Generally, the submit event only fires for valid forms (see Using built-in form validation) — unless you used form.submit().
The submit event's target is its form; it can always be referenced in the handler.

Also note that the Fetch API is promise-based (see Using promises and the async/await keywords).
